# Is it possible to implement delayed (non-strict) arrays on C?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, arrays

I've been exploring with the idea of delayed arrays. If I understand correctly, they're just functions that are used like arrays. So, for example, in JavaScript:

```
// Brief implementation:
array = function(values){
    return function(i){
        if (i>=0 && i<values.length)
            return values[i];
        else
            throw "Out of bound";
    }
};
set = function(array,index,val){
    return function(i){
        return i === index ? val : array(i);
    }
};

// Using:
my_array = array([10,20,30,40]);
assert(my_array(0) === 10);
assert(my_array(1) === 20);
new_array = set(my_array,0,100);
assert(new_array(0) === 100);
```

This has the advantage that you can affect every element in O(1) instead of O(N), at cost of having to amortize it periodically. I have no idea how that could be implemented in C, considering it is not interpreted, so it would probably need constantly recompiling the accessor. Is it doable?

Comment: How does this allow you to affect all elements in O(1)? Also, it is *extremely* wasteful as regards memory allocations. The only thing I can see going for it is that it's basically copy-on-write.

Comment: I don't understand this delayed array concept. Google gives me nothing.

Comment: AFAIK, array access is also O(1) as basically everything that happens is `base + sizeof(type) * n`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'm OK with it being implemented in C++, not C. I should rework my wording!

Comment: @Jon and BWG, say you have this array, [1,2,3,4,5]. Then you have an accessor function. You want to double every element's value. Instead of modifying every element, you modify the **function** that accesses them so it returns the double of the result. So if you only access the 2nd and 3rd elements ever, you didn't have to compute the value of every element and you're happy. Also, if you need to iterate it twice (doubling then doubling) you can fusion that into a single modification. That's the theory. How would it work in C/C++, though?

Comment: @Viclib: You realize that if you *do* access all elements, it's still O(n). So this is not a question of O(1) vs O(n), but rather of lazy vs eager computation. As for how to do it in C, well, the same way you do it in JS: instead of directly reaching into the array, put a function between you and it.

Comment: @Jon but the main benefit is being able to put Fusion to work, so you can, for example. Say `triple_all(triple_all(array))` (for immutable arrays). That won't create dynamically allocated intermediate structures. I realize this is not any useful for C as it is used usually, but it would be useful for my Compile-to-C language.

Comment: @Viclib: Of course *it will* create dynamically allocated intermediate structures. What do you think the values returned from `set` are?

Comment: @Jon hm no? Imagine it as a tuple [acessor,data]. Say you have: `[(λx.x*2),[1,2,3,4]]`, which equals to the array `[2,4,6,8]`. Then you update it, doubling every element: `[(λx.x*2*2),[1,2,3,4]]`, which is now `[4,8,12,16]`. There is no need to update every element in memory, just a little modification on the function.

Comment: @Viclib: Exactly. For every update you make, you need to allocate a new tuple. And that tuple needs to live as long as you might be interested in it. Dynamically allocated structure right there.

Comment: @Jon Be fair, in a good implementation its just a pointer

Comment: @Jon but it don't touch the array, just the function part. So if you have a 100000 or a 100 elements arrays, it is still the same work.

Comment: @Paranaix: The function, as in "the code", is a pointer. The execution context that comes with it, which is what enables the function to work through creating a closure, is not.

Comment: The question boils down to: how do I recompile that function during the execution? That is, I have `int f(int x){return x*x;}`, then I want `int f(int x){return x*x;}`. Is there a fast way to make that kind of modification and get machine code during execution? (Maybe not using strings to avoid the parse, just a structure that "represents" the C functions and can easily be translated to machine code at runtime).

Comment: @Viclib: You are asking how to do something that the code you show does not do in the first place. If the code were using `eval` or `with`, that would be a different beast. But right now there is nothing that would require the C version of this code to modify machine code during execution.

Comment: Makes sense. So independent of the merits of the structure, how would you implement it?

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/dza8eP) could be a really hastily written starting point.

Comment: Access to your lazy arrays becomes slower the more times it has been updated - looking up an element is O(n) on the number of updates *anywhere* in the table. If you were to start with an empty table, and then filled it up with calls to `set`, element access would be exactly O(n).

Answer (score 0):

As shown, this cannot be done in C, but it can be done in C++11 using lambda expressions. The equivalent program is roughly:

```
template <typename T>
auto array(const std::initializer_list <T> values)
{
    return [&](size_t i) { return *(values.begin() + i); };
}

template <typename A, typename T>
auto set(A&& array, size_t index, const T& val)
{
    return [&](size_t i) { return i == index ? val : array(i); };
}

int main ()
{
    auto my_array = array({10,20,30,40});
    assert(my_array(0) == 10);
    assert(my_array(1) == 20);
    auto new_array = set(my_array, 0, 100);
    assert(new_array(0) == 100);
}
```

I did not add the bounds checking, which is not possible within a lambda, but it is possible with an additional function call. The same can be done with custom template function objects also in C++03, but needs much more code.

I am not commenting on the usefulness or efficiency of this approach here, I am only showing a possible way to make it similar to the given Javascript example.

Comment: There is nothing that *requires* those functions to be written inline, hence no need for lambdas. Unless "make the code look the same as the JS example given" is a requirement. The example itself could be easily rewritten without anonymous functions, and this is exactly what all of us were doing to write predicates in C++03.

Comment: Yes of course, this is what I've written below the code; I just wanted to show the similarity to the JS code in the question.